# \lstinputlisting of a whole java project

Tags: listings

I'd like to print the complete source code of my java project, which has multiple `.java` files in several packages (i.e. folders), many `.properties` files and many `.xml` files, and others.

I want to use `\lstinputlisting` from the `listings` package but I don't want to add these commands one by one to the document.

The alternative would be to write some script that generates a file with those `\lstinputlisting` commands for all files, however I'd rather want to know if such a program already exists.

Comment: Something like `find . -name "*.java" | awk '{print "\\lstinputlisting[style=java]{"$0"}";}' >javalistings.tex`?

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Comment: @GabrielBelingueres, that is OK. Either install VBox and put Linux on it (both free) and then mount shared your windows disk into Linux. Or install Cygwin directly into windows, also free. Then you can use the above command by Daniel on windows.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

If you use a Unix OS you can execute the following command:

```bsh
find . -name "*.java" | awk '{print "\\lstinputlisting[style=java]{"$0"}";}' >javalistings.tex
```

If you are using Windows you can install CygWin to get an Unix-Shell.